# How can I change the input method in a Java program on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, internationalization

I am writing a Java application, in which I need to be able to change input languages (say, from English to Japanese) on user request. Normally, a user would just go into the Windows/Linux system settings and change it there. However, for this particular application, the user will not have access to these menus.

I've done quite a bit of research on SO and elsewhere. The solutions I've found indicate using the `InputContext.selectInputMethod([locale])` method. This works on Windows (using the IMEs in the Windows registry), but I can't seem to get it to work on Linux (it always returns false, even when selecting a locale for which I have the appropriate language packs installed).

Ideally, I'd like to have a completely platform independent implementation, but I at least need it to work on Linux. So what am I missing? Do I need to install input methods as an extension? Are there built in IMEs I can use? It seems like this wouldn't be too difficult to implement, but I've found surprisingly little concrete information.

Thanks in advance for the feedback!

Comment: Are you talking about Swing?

Comment: Yes, for example, I 'd like to change the input method in a JTextField.

Comment: Interesting subject. May I ask you another related question? If user does not have access to system language settings, even if app allows user to change the input language to Japaneese for example, the soft keyboard will still look like an English keyboard. How do you handle that ?

Comment: @Alp I may be misunderstanding your question, but my goal is to change all of the appropriate settings programmatically. Thus, I'd be changing the language to Japanese, and the input method to hiragana, katakana, etc.

Comment: @jwhite878 Thanks for the reply. I didn't even know it was possible. Wow.! Thank you again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `input method`? What do you mean by this? The chars that show up as you type? Just asking because Ive done work with Swing and Japanese.

Comment: @user489041 Yes, that's what I'm referring to. Basically, I want to allow Japanese users to type unicode symbols from a standard keyboard. There are ways to do this already (Hiragana, Katakana), but I want to be able to do it platform-independently, or at least on Linux, without accessing the system settings.